# python exit with message and location in code

Tags: python

Within a (rather large) code I have at several places checks and if one of them fails I want the program to exit. Up to now I usually use the `sys.exit()` function with a text inside the brackets, e.g.

`sys.exit('some text')`

However I would also like to give some information where exactly the exit occurred and I do not want to do this manually. Is there some elegant solution around?

Comment: Raise an Exception? Given that you are not doing bare `except:` anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally instead of `sys.exit('text with reason')` you would raise an exception like:

```
raise Exception('text with reason')
```

and you will get the traceback out of the box showing you the exact location of the problem.
Even better if the `fail` you mentioned means an exception is being thrown. Then you don't have to raise your own. Just don't catch the original exception and you are fine.

Comment: That works great. I knew there is a python way of doing it, just could not get my mind twisted enough. Thanks